# video is not being shown in mobile in safari,firefox and chrome but works well on desktop

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js, frontend

I have a website that has video on header, it works fine on desktop except mobile,
I am using next.js 13.4 and this is my code:

```
<video
        id="background-video"
        autoPlay
        playsInline
        loop
        muted
        className="absolute left-0 top-0 w-[100%] h-[100%] object-cover -z-2"
      >
        <source
          src={"./header-webm.webm"}
          type="video/webm"
        />
      </video>
```

also I tried this but again is not working:

```
 <div
        className="absolute left-0 top-0 w-[100%] h-[100%] -z-2 "
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: `<video
           id="background-video"
           autoPlay
           playsInline
           loop
           style="width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: cover;"
         >
           <source
             src="./header-webm.webm"
           />
         </video>`,
        }}
      ></div>
```

also I tried this approach

> https://medium.com/@BoltAssaults/autoplay-muted-html5-video-safari-ios-10-in-react-673ae50ba1f5

but with this the video is not being shown even in chrome desktop.
I got confused ,what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I was just going through this issue as I mentioned in my comment, and I just solved it. Try to change the video extension from mp4 to webm, or use another video that has a webm extension. This workaround solved the issue for me.